# Lengthy \section titles cause strange fancy headers and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

Below is my document. My problem is, that whenever the \section titles are too long, they overlap with the logo and the TOC looks very strange with indents, where there shouldn't by any. Is there a way to reduce the header font size or make it adjust to the section-title length?

Here's [a link](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/hhnsdskddxcx) to the document, where you can see the overlapping etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,titlepage,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%lots of maths packages
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot,framed,enumitem,bbm}

%break after each section
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\vspace{6mm}}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, headheight=12.6pt, includeheadfoot, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}%new borders

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\scshape\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tub_logo.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\setlength\headheight{25pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    {\scshape\Large Technische Universität Berlin \par}
    % title page (omitted text etc. because its not relevant)
\tableofcontents
\end{center}   
\end{titlepage}


\section{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}

text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Did you try to use  the `titletoc` package, since you load `titlesec`? It defines a `rightmargin` length for the table of contents.

Comment: try to make/define shorter section title for page headers: `\section[<short title>]{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}`, where `<short title>` can be something like "Eigenschaften der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz"

Comment: @Bernard No I didn't. Can you please show me how?

Comment: @Zarko Will that affect the header length and/or the TOC ?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik, depends on used document class (memoir support separate options for toc and headers: `\section[<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}`). `article`,  `report`, `book` ... long title will be in text, short in toc and headers.

Answer (score 1):

Her is a solution for the table of contents, based on `titletoc`.

Unrelated: since version 3.10, language options of `babel` should be loaded with the document class, so that all language-dependent packages be aware of the document language. Also you set two values for `\headheight`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, titlepage, twoside, ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

%lots of maths packages
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot,framed,enumitem,bbm}

%break after each section
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\vspace{6mm}}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, headheight=12.6pt, includeheadfoot, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}%new borders

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\scshape\nouppercase{{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tub_logo.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}
\setlength\headheight{25pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}% formatting for numbered sections
{\thecontentslabel\quad\parbox[t]{36pc}}
{}% for unnumbered sections
{\hfill\contentspage}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    {\scshape\Large Technische Universität Berlin \par}
    % title page (omitted text etc. because its not relevant)
\tableofcontents
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\section{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}

\lipsum

\section{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}

\lipsum

\section{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}

\lipsum

\section{Vollständigkeit, Kompaktheit, endliche Durchschnittseigenschaft und der Banachsche Fixpunktsatz}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! What does {\hfill\contentspage} do? And how do I get the TOC on my title page? ( Everything I have on my title page fills approximately the upper half, and since the TOC won't be that long, I would like to have it all on one page).

Comment: `\hfill\contentspage` prints the page number at the right margin, ragged right. As to your second question, as you can see, the title and the table of contents are already on the same page. If you want to be sure they remain on the same page, as this depends on what you put in the title page, you might want to take a look at the `titling` package, which gives tools to customise the `\maketitle` command and defines a `titlingpage` environment.

Comment: In my document, the toc is not on the title page. Also, I only see the page number on the bottom center. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Do you use the `article` class, as in your post? Also what do you mean with ‘only the page number at the bottom center’ – you obtain the `plain` page style?

Comment: Yes I do use article and concerning your second question: you said ''\hfill\contentspage prints the page number at the right margin, ragged right.'', but I don't see the page number at the right margin...

Comment: The page number of a section in the toc (2, 2, 3, 4 at the right of the toc in the image I posted). I'm not sure we're speaking of the same page numbers.